# Knife cookbook missing commands

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Knife cookbook is missing all commands except metadata. When running `knife cookbook --help` I get the following output:

```
$knife cookbook --help 
FATAL: Cannot find sub command for: 'cookbook --help'
Available cookbook subcommands: (for details, knife SUB-COMMAND --help)

** COOKBOOK COMMANDS **
knife cookbook metadata COOKBOOK (options)
```

I'm running on Windows 7 and also tried to install the latest chef-dk (0.6.2) with no luck.

Do you have any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the subcommand part. So

`knife cookbook create --help` gives you details on the `create` command.

If you want a list of all commands available, just try `knife cookbook`.

Comment: Still no luck. When typing the suggested command I still get: `$ knife cookbook create --help
FATAL: Cannot find sub command for: 'cookbook create --help'
Available cookbook subcommands: (for details, knife SUB-COMMAND --help)

** COOKBOOK COMMANDS **
knife cookbook metadata COOKBOOK (options)
`

Comment: Looks like there might also be a bug on windows https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/3272

Comment: Thanks a lot. Downgrading to an older version indeed solved the issue.